# Как выполнить window.location в новом окне, если зажата клавиша ctrl?

Tags: html, css, jquery, link, href

Есть кнопка, котороой в JS-переменной задана ссылка. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на неё ссылка открывалась внутри текущей вкладки, а при удерживании клавиши <kbd>ctrl</kbd> происходило target="_blank"?

```js
$(".button").mouseup(function() {
  var currLink = 'https://site.ru/';
  window.location = currLink;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: `window.open(…)`

Comment: Впрочем лучше вместо кнопки сделать ссылку и не заниматься странным

Comment: Про window.open(…) знаю, у меня возникли скорее проблемы с тем, чтобы сделать правильный if else по параметру нажатия

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вот так вот:

```js
$(".button").on('mousedown', function(e) {
  let currLink = 'https://site.ru/';
  
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    window.open(currLink, "_blank");
  } else {
    window.open(currLink, "_self");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Если кому нужно, чтобы при _blank не выполнялось переключения вкладки, ставим в if {} window.focus(); после первого выражения